# Run custom command before flutter build?

Tags: flutter, dart, protocol-buffers

I'm building a flutter app that uses protocal buffers and I would like to compile the `.proto` file during the build process. How can I run a custom shell command before the dart compilation of a flutter build?

Comment: I don't know of a built in method if it exists anyway but Have you considered writing a batch or shell script

Comment: That's what I'm currently using. I would like to integrate into the default build system if possible though.

Comment: Check this package https://dart.dev/tools/build_runner

Answer (score 7):

I believe you can do this in Android Studio.

**1. Go to `Run > Edit Configurations`**

[image]

**2. Add a new Shell Script configuration from `(+) Add New Configuration > Shell Script`**

[image]

**3. Setup your shell script execution. Make sure to click on `Apply` after you're done. But don't close it yet.**

[image]

**4. Select `Flutter > Run/main.dart > Before Launch > (+)Add > Run Another Configuration`**

[image]

**5. Choose your Shell Script configuration**

[image]

**6. Click `Apply` then click `OK`. Your configured Shell Script will now run.**

[image]

Comment: This works well if you're developing the app solo, but if you're on a team, each member will need to do this. On our team, some of us use Android Studio, while others use VS Code.

Comment: I think the configuration can be committed to the repository. We have a .run folder in our codebase and another called .vscode.
Not sure if it can be done on VScode though

Answer (score 6):

Flutter doesn't have this capability yet, it's kind of better to have a pre-build script.

### Simple Pre-build Script

*my-pre-build.sh*

```sh
# my-pre-build.sh (run some commands)
```

*Usage*

```sh
./my-pre-build.sh && flutter build apk
```

### Using Make to Abstract the Build

You could also abstract the build using something like a [Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), which makes things simpler in my opinion.

*Makefile (in root of your project)*

```
# Build for Android (runs build-proto first)
build-apk: build-proto
    flutter test
    flutter build apk

# Build for iOS (runs build-proto first)
build-ios: build-proto
    flutter test
    flutter build ios

# Proto generation (calls terminal proto commands)
build-proto:
    proto-native-lib compile -f *.proto
```

*Usage*

```sh
make build-android
make build-ios
```

This is a useful way to bundle repetitive commands and reuse scripts between different build types.

Comment: This solution makes the most sense, until Flutter team introduces something built-in.

Answer (score 1):

In case you'd like to consider something different, I accomplish exactly what you are requesting by using an external build tools. In my case I chose https://fastlane.tools/, which neatly integrates with Flutter, works for Android and iOS and it's open source.